# Inconsistent error while creating database in DB2: SQL0440N

Tags: db2, db2-luw

I'm running this command in db2:

```
create database testdb pagesize 32768 temporary tablespace managed by automatic storage;
```

Sometimes the result is:

```
     [exec] SQL0440N  No authorized routine named "SYSIBMADM.DBMS_LOB.COMPARE" of type 
     [exec] "FUNCTION" having compatible arguments was found.  LINE NUMBER=1.  
     [exec] SQLSTATE=42884
```

Other times it works though. Is there some additional configuration I need to do to get this to work consistently? Could it be a resource issue?

I'm using this [DB2 docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/ibmcom/db2) in a testing environment in an on prem Kubernetes test environment.

Additionally, I'm executing the command from another container using DB2's runtime client to the remote database server.

Comment: Check two places in Db2-server container for more diagnostics, first in the os messages log, second in the Db2 diagnostics file, then edit your question to include new details. There's not enough detail in your question for others to reproduce it.  Does the symptom happen if you don't have a second container involved (i.e. run everything in server image)?

Comment: Ok, I'll look at those locations to see if I can find additional information. Testing in in the server image directly won't work for my use case, and will take some work to get it all running together, so I'm hoping to avoid that for now.

Answer (score 0):

Please see if this helps: Create database might fail with SQL0440N error. https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21616147

Any of the following could be the reason:

1) The server time was reset or changed.
2) The database was restored on a server with a different time or time zone.
3) The time associated with the members in multi-partitionned database environments is out of sync.

Note : The time may look correct from the minutes and second standpoint, but the milliseconds could actually be off.

Are you creating database in multi-node system?

Comment: Hmm, that's interesting. I'll see what I can find on the system in regards to the time sync issues. Do you think it could it be due to the client and server setup? 

This isn't a multi-node system though.